# VBA to copy up to row group

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

my pivot table has 2 row values and i would like to copy the values within one group using VBA. It does not work out for me though

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "0-2", xlDataAndLabel, True
Selection.Copy
```

[sample pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeRpU.png)

Comment: It works fine for me,
Just put Selection.Copy in the line below to ActiveSheet.PivotTables...

Comment: Ohhh but the xlDataAndLabel copies the 0-2 header plus the full data in that group.. So my copy values have 3 columns but i only meed the first column of data.. Should i change to ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "0-2", xlLabelOnly + _xlFirstRow, True